# Do questions have to restate all implications of supplied content to be acceptable?

Tags: discussion, questions, closed-questions

In other words, do questions have to meet encyclopedia level verbiage requirements to be helpful?

In the case of this question on Server Fault (which I didn't pose):

[Debian update failed](https://serverfault.com/questions/1117773/debian-update-failed)

My first attempt at finding a solution to this was to do a search for NO_PUBKEY B53DC80D13EDEF05 and this question was among the top hits. Isn't that enough to satisfy some base criterion? That is, the answer is found on a Stack Overflow site after a simple search... and it currently has 10 upvotes (before mine) and so it was helpful to others as well.

The question is pretty self-evident with respect to what was done, is not really cryptic, and the expected outcome is naturally deduced: apt update and a successful index update respectively. I'd edit the question to improve, but I'm not sure how I would elaborate on it without stating what can be derived from the current content of it.

Sure there was little *apparent* or mentioned attempt to find answers on Google's SDK release pages, but now that the answer is on Server Fault, the solution is not buried on some page 2 (plus) of a Google search, or inside a question that is less direct. This closed answer was the top hit on Google Search. It feels like a win to me

So I wonder what the goal is: to make people self-sufficient or to inform? Maybe a little of both? If you've been around a while, you'll remember [RTFM](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/RTFM#Phrase). Those four letters are everywhere on the Internet: forums, etc.; and they have never supplied anyone with a good answer.

Comment: Depends on the site and the question. Should this be asked on [serverfault meta](https://meta.serverfault.com/) since it's a bit specific? You know this is main meta?

Comment: I started to post there, but don't really know the political boundaries for this kind of question. I guess a 'good question' would be decided by the most specific meta. But I was wondering how far up the meta chain to go since the RTFM discussion is an old one and thought there may have been codified policies somewhere up there.

Comment: I'm not really going to reopenhammer this but I feel like while SF was an example - the 'broad' issue is of somewhat more pertinence to any of the 'tech' related communities

Comment: "they have never supplied anyone with a good answer" It is always a good answer, and people not doing it & not doing it is why there is a F in it.

Comment: I disagree @philipxy. That's about the person, not the question. Access to the F manual can be limited for, or just not yet found. And the Internet can provide ways around that kind of limitation when 'forums' like this that are easily reached with searches etc. How many tablespoons in a cup? Read The F Physics Manual? No, when you can find people who have decided to attempt to help with that on easily searchable sites. Nobody asks what temperature, what material. They guess at reasonable defaults that have the best chance of being helpful. TTPAGFA - Try to Provide a Good F Answer is better

Answer (score 4):

Well, to an extent, it needs to show what you've done and the *information* one needs to answer the question.

Let’s dissect the question

> Err:19 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk InRelease
> The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B53DC80D13EDEF05 NO_PUBKEY FEEA9169307EA071

And the comments

> What is the Debian version you are trying to update? What steps have you taken to update?

While it’s *useful* that it’s Debian, we can't tell if the issue is due to 'no key existing' - from running an older version *or* the key never being added.

Since this isn't a default repository, the OP must have added it somehow, and showing 'where' you got the instructions for adding it would be useful.

While the instructions in the answer 'help', it’s a 'different' problem (expired cert/signing keys) that happens to solve the same problem (OP missed a step, or was unaware of a step).

Ironically, a well explained question setting out what you tried *is* better for the casual passerby since it *allows the answers* to teach.

Back in the day, when I had the bandwidth to write lots of comments, I used to write something along the lines of "Welcome to <site> - in order for us to help us help you, we may need a little more information on what you have tried and done so far"

> IOW, do questions have to meet encyclopedia level verbiage requirements to be helpful?

No. We *do* need to understand the user's *unique* environment and the actions that have lead to this point. *What* is user's goal? What is the user's actions so far? Can we skip any steps they have so far.

A good question isn't college essay length. It’s also not two lines.

In the user's shoes

I'd write it as such - any bold letters is commentary

> I am running Debian $ver inside a google cloud computing environment **(or on my own system, or on a potato)**. I am running apt-update and am getting the following error
>
> ```
> Err:19 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk InRelease
>
> The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B53DC80D13EDEF05 NO_PUBKEY FEEA9169307EA07
> ```
>
> It worked fine before **(or I added the repository based on the guide at $site)**
> How do I get this to work correctly?

So we have

1. the environment
2. the actions/inactions before the issue
3. the intended end state.

This helps when there are quirks to a platform, or for [SMEs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject-matter_expert) in that platform to answer the question better.

Comment: Thanks, I'll munch on that for a bit. Good points here are 'debian version' and possibly whether the key was ever installed. But I really think that the latter is an independent thing since the result would be the same in either case.
Likewise, the env (cloud) is not really relevant in this case since this could be debian inside or outside a cloud env and the result would be the same.
That leaves the 'end state' which I think should be very obvious and really doesn't need to be stated IMO.
Thanks for the answer

Comment: There may be quirks to it - and in some cases repositories installed by cloud or dedi providers by default. My dedi provider uses their 'own' mirrors on the default installs for example, or there may be cloud/vm specific bugs. Its *always* useful to have clear indications of your working environment.

Comment: Also in theory, it makes for better SEO?

Comment: Ok, but anyone who is searching for this pub key and those who use the sdk would know that it is installed by snap by default so that apt package is only relevant if you installed it yourself. And the cloud provider is the owner of the repo so redirecting it elsewhere from inside the env wouldn't make much sense here. Also this was the #1 SEO hit for my search :) But, I see where your coming from

Comment: I don't think debian has snap. Its very much an ubuntuism. *and* ubuntu sometimes hides snap under apt a lot of time . And very much why the 'how you got here' is as important as 'where you are' and the 'where you want to be'

Comment: True that Debian doesn't use snap and google installs the sdk on Debian images using apt repo's: the goog's *own* repos. The cloud provider redirecting to a different apt source still doesn't make sense. They are the authority here. Whether the person installed it themselves (using google docs) or it was already installed, the repos are the same.

Comment: Adding google's repos cause you're following a guide blindly or blindly copying config files from another system could have the same effect. Information on the operating environment is *absolutely* one place its worth not skimping on.

Comment: The error surfaced for anyone who installed using the documented procedure: not following them blindly, but following them verbatim. The key changed  in December '22 and since sysadmin's do 1000 things at once, the announcement could be easily overlooked. I'd go as far as to say, anyone who saw the announcement before running into this error was prob just lucky.